# Why I got errors on problem in codewars python?

Tags: python

Problem:
The new "Avengers" movie has just been released! There are a lot of people at the cinema box office standing in a huge line. Each of them has a single 100, 50 or 25 dollar bill. An "Avengers" ticket costs 25 dollars.

Vasya is currently working as a clerk. He wants to sell a ticket to every single person in this line.

Can Vasya sell a ticket to every person and give change if he initially has no money and sells the tickets strictly in the order people queue?

Return YES, if Vasya can sell a ticket to every person and give change with the bills he has at hand at that moment. Otherwise return NO.
Examples:

```py
tickets([25, 25, 50]) # => YES 
tickets([25, 100]) # => NO. Vasya will not have enough money to give change to 100 dollars
tickets([25, 25, 50, 50, 100]) # => NO. Vasya will not have the right bills to give 75 dollars of change (you can't make two bills of 25 from one of 50)
```

My code:

```py
def tickets(people):
    money = 0

    for ticket in people:
        if ticket == 25:
            money += ticket
        else:
            if money >= ticket - 25:
                money += 25
                money -= ticket - 25
            else:
                return "NO"

    return "YES"
```

I got 4 errors: "YES should equal NO" and "NO should equal YES"
Where is my mistake?

Comment: Please copy-paste text *as text* into your question. Images of text are bad, and links are worse. Questions need to be self-contained and text-only as much as possible. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

You should keep track of the number of each kind of bills you have in stock instead of just the total money you have. To do that, you can use a dict (or `collections.OrderedDict`, if you're using a Python version older than 3.6) to map each bill value to the number of that bill you have in stock, from the largest bills to the smallest. For each bill tender from a customer, the target change will be the bill value minus 25. Then iterate through the dict keys and deduct from the target change and the stock the number of that type of bill in order to satisfy the target change, or the number of it you have in stock, whichever is smaller. If the target change is still not zero after you iterate through all types of bills you have in stock, it means you can't satisfy the required target change, so return `'NO'`; otherwise add the current bill tender to the stock. Return `'YES'` in the end if you are able to satisfy all customers.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def tickets(people):
    stock = OrderedDict.fromkeys((100, 50, 25), 0)
    for tender in people:
        change = tender - 25
        for bill, count in stock.items():
            deduct = min(change // bill, count)
            change -= deduct * bill
            stock[bill] -= deduct
        if change:
            return 'NO'
        stock[tender] += 1
    return 'YES'
```

Comment: Thank you but I got 1 error 'NO' should equal 'YES'

Comment: My guess is that the grader uses an older Python version. Try changing `dict` to `collections.OrderedDict` like I mentioned in the answer. I've updated my sample code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

solution:

```
def tickets(people):
    a = 0
    for i in people:
        if i == 25:
            a += i
        else:           
            if a >= i - 25:
                return "YES"
            else:
                return "NO"
```